# How to do a MySql 'id' lookup based on array and save results in a new array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array with a lot (100-800) of id's.
I want to query my database doing a lookup on the id's from my array with any matches from the database and then save the matching results in a new array.

**My array:**

```
//print_r($_POST["fb_friend_uid"])
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 263901486
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 502533736
        )
)
```

--1. Then I try to see if any values from the array matches with records in the database - **is this the correct way to do this?**:

```
$ids = join(',',$_POST["fb_friend_uid"]);

SELECT *
FROM vote WHERE
vote_fb_uid IN ($ids)
AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vote_time)) = DATE(NOW())";
```

--2. **Then im struggling to save the matching records in a new array - this is what ive tried with:**

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $savedResultsInNewArray=[$row['vote_fb_uid']];
}
```

Im looking to return the new array in a format of: echo `json_encode($savedResultsInNewArray);`

Im a bit unsure the above is the right way to do that?

Comment: there's multiple steps here, which one is failing, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is to get your ID's from the array. You can do this with a loop:

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST["fb_friend_uid"] as $uid) {
    $uids[] = $uid['id'];
}

$ids = join(',', $uids);

/*
 * Query is correct
 *
 * SELECT *
 * FROM vote WHERE
 * vote_fb_uid IN ($ids)
 * AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vote_time)) = DATE(NOW())";
*/

// For the returning part.

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $savedResultsInNewArray[] = $row['vote_fb_uid'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Farkie - thanks so much for your response!

I almost think I got it working. I tried adjusting my query to hardcoded id numbers, that I ran in Phpmyadmin, which gives me 2 results. However when I print_r($savedResultsInNewArray); then I only get 1 result - so doesnt seem all result data is saved in the new array - any idea?

Comment: I modified the bottom part slightly, adding the []

Comment: Sry, dont think i see any updates? :) - atleast $savedResultsInNewArray[] = $row['vote_fb_uid']; has been there from the start :) and is what im doing now

Comment: I didn't change my code - I mean I've modified it from your version of the code, `$savedResultsInNewArray[] = $row['vote_fb_uid']`. This creates an array of the uid's pulled from the database. The thing that does it is the **[** and **]**

Comment: Hmm weird - tried running your exact bottom part and can inly output one result from the new array - although running my $query directly in the database tells me I should get 2 results

Comment: Just tried to do a direct query which gives me 5 results - however the array only prints out 4 results - so seems one record is left out